# Gif not appearing on manually entered constraints

Tags: ios, swift, gif, nslayoutconstraint, addsubview

My code below is trying to load a gif on a image view. This code works when the code use the constraints on a storyboard however when I write the nslayout constraints the gif does not appear. There is no runtime or compile error the gif is just not appearing.

```
let FIRE = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    FIRE.loadGif(name: "FIRE")

    view.addSubview(FIRE)

    FIRE.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    FIRE.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    FIRE.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
    FIRE.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the view's autoresizing mask to set constraints manually:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // 1) turn off autoresizing mask
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // 2) set contraints
    self.setupSubviews()

    // 3) update the view
    imageView.loadGif(name: "FIRE")

}

func setupSubviews() {
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)


    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```